# Automating Title Capitalization in Sections, Subsections, etc

Tags: titlesec, capitalization, stringstrings

I'm trying to automate the capitalization of titles in sections, subsections, etc. Basically, I'd like to format every title with `\capitalize` from the `stringstrings` package. One approach I've tried is to use the `\titleformat` command from the `\titlesec` package, but I'm getting errors. For example:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{\thesection}{1em}{\capitalizetitle}
```

What am I missing? Maybe I don't know how to properly use the above command.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

**EDIT**

After the suggestions given below, I created an MWE that raises errors when having bibliography citation.

File test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% Language support
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Get everything translated properly
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Input text correctly
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Get hyphenation right
\usepackage{lmodern} % The Latin Modern fonts
%%%

%%% AMS support
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}   % fonts
\usepackage{amssymb}    % extra symbols
%%%

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

\usepackage{titlesec,titlecaps}

\Addlcwords{is with}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\thesection.\;}{0pt}{\formatsectiontitle}
\newcommand{\formatsectiontitle}[1]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\titlecap{#1}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\thesubsection.\;}{0pt}{\formatsubsectiontitle}
\newcommand{\formatsubsectiontitle}[1]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\titlecap{#1}}


\begin{document}

\section{this is a title 1}

\subsection{this is a Subsection Title 1}

\section{Another title 2}

Please see \cite{author2016}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test_bib}

\end{document}
```

File test_bib.bib:

```
@Article{author2016,
author = {Last Name, F. N.},
title = {{Title of the Paper}},
journal = {Journal X.},
volume = {130},
number = {20},
pages = {6342-6344},
year = {2016}
}
```

Then calling:

pdflatex -> works

bibtex -> works

pdflatex -> error

The error is given below:

```
! Argument of \ttl@gmk has an extra }.

\par
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{5}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?

**EDIT 2**

Following suggestions, the new file test.tex below compiles with no errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% Language support
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Get everything translated properly
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Input text correctly
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Get hyphenation right
\usepackage{lmodern} % The Latin Modern fonts
%%%

%%% AMS support
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}   % fonts
\usepackage{amssymb}    % extra symbols
%%%

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

\usepackage{titlesec,titlecaps}

\let\titlecap\relax \def\Addlcwords#1{}

\Addlcwords{is with}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\thesection.\;}{0pt}{\formatsectiontitle}
\newcommand{\formatsectiontitle}[1]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\titlecap{#1}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\thesubsection.\;}{0pt}{\formatsubsectiontitle}
\newcommand{\formatsubsectiontitle}[1]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\titlecap{#1}}


\begin{document}

\section{this is a title 1}

\subsection{this is a Subsection Title 1}

\section{Another title 2}

Please see \cite{author2016}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test_bib}

\end{document}
```

pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex produces the result below. The problem now is that the titles are not automatically capitalized.

[image: Output]

Comment: First, I recommend the use of the `titlecaps` package, rather than `stringstrings`, for the purpose of achieving Title Case (I wrote both packages).  However, in both cases, the macros are not mode commands, but need to take an argument, so I am not sure they are compatible with the approach you are proposing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED (See **SUPPLEMENT** for compatibility with `natbib`)

I stand corrected from my comment.  It can be done.  I followed the example of [Chapter title alignment with titleformat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111251/chapter-title-alignment-with-titleformat) but made it to title caps, instead of small caps.

I even employed the word exclusion available from `\Addlcwords{}`.

In my original comment to the OP, I recommended the use of the `titlecaps` package, which I wrote precisely because the `\capitalizetitle` macro of the `stringstrings` package (which I also wrote) was embarrassingly slow.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,titlecaps}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {}
  {\llap{\color{gray}\chapterNumber\thechapter
   \hspace{10pt}\vline}}
  {10pt}
  {\formatchaptertitle}

\newcommand{\formatchaptertitle}[1]{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-10pt}{\raggedright\LARGE\titlecap{#1}}}

\newcommand{\chapterNumber}{%
  \fontsize{50}{50}\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}}

\Addlcwords{is with}
\begin{document}
\chapter{this is my long long long long title with several lowercase words}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

Apparently, the use of `\titlecap` in section titles via `titlesec` is incompatible with `natbib`.  The solution here was to `\let\titlecap\relax` *immediately prior to the bibliography call*, which essentially turns off `titlecap` for the bibliography.  But since the section name of the bibliography is "References" and does not need `\titlecap`, there is no harm is so doing.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%% Language support
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Get everything translated properly
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % Input text correctly
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Get hyphenation right
\usepackage{lmodern} % The Latin Modern fonts
%%%
%%% AMS support
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}   % fonts
\usepackage{amssymb}    % extra symbols
%%%
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

\usepackage{titlesec,titlecaps}

\Addlcwords{is with}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\thesection.\;}{0pt}{\formatsectiontitle}
\newcommand{\formatsectiontitle}[1]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\titlecap{#1}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\thesubsection.\;}{0pt}{\formatsubsectiontitle}
\newcommand{\formatsubsectiontitle}[1]{\normalfont\large\bfseries\titlecap{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{this is a title 1}

\subsection{this is a Subsection Title 1}

\section{Another title 2}

Please see \cite{author2016}.

\let\titlecap\relax
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test_bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions and example, Steven! It's difficult to get a better answer than from the creator of the package! :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm running into errors when I use your solution and have a bibliography section. Please see the edited OP. Thanks!

Comment: As you have witnessed, I can't claim infallibility.  It would help those trying to answer if you could post a complete (small) example, starting with `\documentclass`, which demonstrates the issue.  As a side note, sometimes the order in which packages are loaded can influence results.

Comment: I added an MWE. Hopefully it's helpful for debugging.

Comment: @Bruno First thing I did was to turn off `titlecaps` by invoking `\let\titlecap\relax \def\Addlcwords#1{}` in the preamble to turn off titlecap features.  One can even remove its mention in `\usepackage`.  If `titlecap` were the problem, then this should work.  When I try to `pdflatex` it the 2nd time, I get various errors: I am not a bib expert.  Did you invoke `bibtex` for the 2nd round, or something like `natbib`?

Comment: Please see the EDIT 2 part above with your suggestions. it's almost working!

Comment: @Bruno See **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer.

Comment: Need this solution as well. However, is there a way to get the TOC titles to match with the new letter case section headings?

Comment: @AustinBenny I do not know how to resolve the toc issue, I am sorry.